# Is there a significant performance difference between '==' and '==='?

Tags: javascript

I follow the practice of always using a absolute comparison '===', but some learned colleagues have argued that this is an unnecessary waste of computation time on type-checking in situations where you're highly confident of a particular comparison type.

So my question is this; is there realistically any significant performance hit for always type-checking values during comparison?

Comment: Did you try measuring the performance difference ?

Comment: `==` coerces values to perform the check, so an argument can be made in favor of `===` as well.

Comment: Look at [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: " ... **significant** performance difference..." Most likely not. But try yourself: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: The term "significant performance difference" makes no sense outside of the context of specific code. Most likely the equality operator you use will not be the performance bottleneck but it really depends.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum this question doesn't seem to have proper answers on the performance topic. On this, I know I did measurements a long time ago and was disappointed to be unable to see anything. So on the "significant" thing, I can only agree with Felix.

Comment: [no significative (nor reliably reproductible) difference](http://jsperf.com/equalitydoubletriple/5).

Comment: @dystroy even if you don't like the _answers_ it's the same question, and I quote: `Is there a performance benefit to replacing == with ===?`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum There's no point, in my opinion, in linking to a more general question which has no answer at all on the specific question asked by monners.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably not a significant performance difference if the objects are already of the same type. Both operators have to look up and compare the types of the two arguments before doing the data comparison.

If the objects are of different types, `===` should be a little faster, since it can return `false` immediately, while `==` will coerce one of the arguments to the other type and then perform the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There's a test of this at jsperf:

Take a look and try it yourself: http://jsperf.com/equalitydoubletriple/4

**Edit:** This test may be better, as @dystroy mentions in the comment below: http://jsperf.com/equalitydoubletriple/5

Comment: Won't this be browser dependent.. ?

Comment: Indeed.  But all tests are logged so you can see a chart of difference between browsers as well. It's not the final answer, but you may get an idea at least.

Comment: Yes, it will. So you'd need to run it on different browsers to see if it's better in all/some/none.

Comment: This test is misleading as it tests the case where a type change is needed. A better one would be http://jsperf.com/equalitydoubletriple/5

Comment: `==` is 6% slower.. ? :O

Comment: Here is a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/strict-vs-abstract-comparison) with an unfair advantage to the strict version. I tested the most of steps described in [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)

Answer (score 1):

There's no significant performance difference between `==` and `===`. The only difference between them is the type comparison. `==` comparison can be used even when the 2 conditions have different type. `===` comparison only accept comparison between 2 same type conditions. Example: when `int` and `char` can be compared with `==`, `===` comparison can't be used.